# How to reopen the new minecraft launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

So I've been using the new Minecraft launcher since I received it without really caring about the difference, but recently when I open the shortcut on my taskbar it tries to confirm if I want to exit the launcher or reset my config due to me using a newer launcher:

[image: Pichta]

So I wouldn't really mind using the old launcher again but the thing that I'm worried about is resetting my settings/configuration. Does this mean my profiles on the launcher? Or might it actually mean my Minecraft worlds? Also, will it delete my versions as well?

The path that the shortcut gives me is:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe"

I would prefer to be able to return to the old version but don't mind the new launcher.

**Note**

This seems to have fixed itself. I will leave the question open though, in case there's an answer and someone needs it.

Comment: Resetting your config *shouldn't* reset your saves but it might end up deleting any profile configurations you have set up. Versions should stay also.

Comment: If you want to submit that as an answer I'll accept that ;) . I'm going to reset it but back it up first. Aand if your correct I'll give you a cookie :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting your config *shouldn't* reset your saves but it might end up deleting any profile configurations you have set up. Versions should stay also.

Comment: Did it end up working?

Comment: Heres a Cookie :D

Comment: Haven't tested it yet, but more googling says that your answer is correct ;) Its reseting launcher configurations.

Comment: No problemo ;) good luck